# WIndows Azure CentOS expand OS drive

Tags: azure, centos, expand, partition

In windows azure I would like to expand my CentOS OS drive to use 100gb instead of the 30gb default. What is the easiest way to do this? I looked at a lot of tutorials but they all relate to windows vm's. Does anyone have a walk through I could look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only option right now is to pull the VHD file down to your local environment and use tools to resize and then upload and attach to a new VM.  While this is about a Windows VM it's essentially what you'll need to do: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devkeydet/archive/2012/07/05/resizing-an-azure-vm-vhd-file.aspx. To be honest you'd probably be better to just create a new VM and pull across the instance data from the old one by mounting the old VM's drive on your new one.